# html password cached in RAM?

Tags: passwords, encryption

My server is configured with https. But all credentials are cached in RAM (client machine).

If we have the IP address of the client machine we can easily fetch the user credentials which are stored in RAM. I understand that RAM doesn't get cleared unless you turn off/reboot the client machine.

How can I stop the caching of credentials in RAM?

Comment: How are you caching the credentials in RAM in first place. Just re-do it.

Comment: Its automatically caching whenever user tries to login the application

Comment: Nothing is automatic. What is in RAM will be in some variable or some thing. Revising it's content will change what is in RAM

Comment: i didn't understand it. Can you please explain it? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

When you run a web server, you accept connections from a web browser like Chrome, Safari, or Internet Explorer on the client machine.   When your client connects via https, the information that browser sends you, and the information you send back to that browser, are concealed by encryption while in transit.

The user provides her username and password to a dialog box in the browser software, which then manages its transmission (encrypted) to your server.  The browser does indeed store the username and password unencrypted.  It needs to do this, because BASIC authentication requires each request to the server to carry the (encrypted) username/password pair.

If the user loses control of her machine while it is switched on, then a bad guy can indeed discover the password.

It is up to the browser software to wipe passwords from RAM when it exits.  Most commercial browser software packages clear that RAM before exiting.

If you are creating a special purpose browser (a special purpose https client software package) you might wish to do the same.

Your concern is valid: it is one reason that viruses and other malware are such a hazard. But if you are an ordinary web developer, there's nothing you can do about this client-side risk except recommend that your users install and maintain anti-virus software.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. One quick question, is it possible to clear the ram on exit (via scripting)?

Comment: There is no easy way for a script sent from the server side to access (to read or write) the RAM holding clear-text passwords on the client side. If there were it would be a security hole.  Again, unless you are developing a special purpose client side browser you don't need to worry about this issue.